# C++ vector of unique pointers

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
class FurnitureShop {
    static const int FURNITURE_RESUPPLY = 50;

    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Employee>> employees;
    int completedTasks;

public:
    FurnitureShop(std::string name);
    void addEmployee(std::unique_ptr<Employee> &&employee);
    //...
```

Attribute of this class 'employees' contains vector of unique pointers. I want to implement method addEmployee:

```
void FurnitureShop::addEmployee(unique_ptr<Employee> &&employee) {
    this->employees.insert(employee.operator*());
}
```

where I suggest method .operator*() should make an access to the first object where unique pointer is. Anyway, as I get result, this is not working well (or as intended). Could you guide me where did I do mistake?

Comment: I guess `shared_ptr` makes more sense here as `Employee` object can have a lifetime outside of `FurnitureShop` object as well or is it by design that `Employee` objects won't exist outside of the `FurnitureShop` object?

Answer (score 5):

`employee.operator*()` is the same as `*employee`. Which means that you attempt to insert the actual `Employee` object, not the unique pointer.

You should move the unique pointer object itself into the vector:

```
void FurnitureShop::addEmployee(unique_ptr<Employee> employee) {
    employees.emplace_back(std::move(employee));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are inserting the underlying raw pointer from `employee` (which in this case remains owned by `employee` and gets destroyed in the destructor for the `std::unique_ptr` which is passed as the parameter), while what you want is to move the passed `std::unique_ptr` itself (since you are already passing an rvalue reference, even though the signatures in your snippet do not match). What happens now is that you insert the raw pointer and it gets deleted when the function argument gets destroyed.

What you want is:

```cpp
void FurnitureShop::addEmployee(unique_ptr<Employee> &&employee) {
    this->employees.emplace_back(std::move(employee));
}
```